# PHP: How do I sum array values according to the options the user selected inside an html form?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I´m trying to sum the values of a form that´s filled in by the user. I´m just learning PHP, I´m sorry for this n00b question :)

Here´s a quick example of how is my html form:

```
...
What´s your favourite month?
<input type ="checkbox" name="month[]" value="march">March<br>
<input type ="checkbox" name="month[]" value="april">April

What´s your favourite day of the week?
<select name="day[]">
<option value="monday">Monday</option>
<option value="friday">Friday</option>
</select>
```

So, inside my php file I put:

```
/*Declare the variables here*/
$month = $_POST["month"];
$day = $_POST["day"];

/*Assign a value to each variable*/
$month = array (
"march" => 10,
"april" => 20);

$day = array (
"monday" => 1,
"friday" => 2);

$number = array_sum($month + $day);

print "<br>Your magic Number is... <b>".$total."</b>.<br>"
```

I can´t make this work, because the array just sums all the values, and not just the ones that the user selected inside the form. I can imagine that I´m telling exactly that with array_sum(). So how can I tell the script to sum just the values that the user selected?

Thanks for your advice!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back at this, you shouldn't need an array for the select as this is not a multiselect and they can only pick one option. So in your html you can just have this

```
<select name="day">
  <option value="monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="friday">Friday</option>
</select>
```

For the PHP

```
$total = 0; 

/*Assign a value to each variable*/
$month = array (
"march" => 10,
"april" => 20);

$day = array (
"monday" => 1,
"friday" => 2);

foreach( $_POST['month'] as $k => $v )
{
   if( isset($month[ $v ]) )
       $total += $month[ $v ]; 
} 

if( isset($day[ $_POST['day'] ]) 
    $total += $day[ $_POST['day'] ];      

print "<br>Your magic Number is... <b>".$total."</b>.<br>"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but for some reason it won´t take some values (the ones that are inside the lists where the user can select only 1 otion), and it gives you an error when a field is left blank (Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()).                              Thanks for your help guys, yes, maybe this is too much for a newbie, but I´ve learn so much trying once and again stuff like this..

Comment: I´m trying with if(is_array($_POST['month'])){....}  but it still won´t calculate some of the arrays... I mean is like some of the $_POST['X'] variables are not selected by the user, and they are not count in the final sum.

Answer (score 2):

You're making this problem for yourself because you are assigning the $month value the POST date from the form, but then you're assigning the same variable $month as an array.

To get a value from an array, you don't need an array_sum() function. Also you're not assigning the $total variable any value, you're calling it $number.

Try this instead, and make sure to follow the logic of your variables when coding next time. If you are asking a favorite month, are you sure you want to give them the option of selecting more than one? This example doesn't allow for more than one answer, but there are several logic problems with your existing code that you can address if that is actually what you want. For single options, give them radio buttons instead of check boxes.

```
//Get actual values chosen by the user in a form
$user_month = $_POST["month"];
$user_day = $_POST["day"];

//Define the values for each possible answer
$month = array (
"march" => 10,
"april" => 20);

$day = array (
"monday" => 1,
"friday" => 2);

//Get the value of both added together if that is what you want
$number = $month[$user_month] + $day[$user_day];

print "<br>Your magic Number is... <b>".$number."</b>.<br>"
```

To get the multiple values like you are doing in the first example ("What are ALL your favorite months?") you will need to do a loop through the result array, $user_month in the above example, and add each value to the total until you get to the end of the $user_month array, then do the same for the $user_day array.

Try working through some basic PHP starting tutorials or get a beginner book and work through all the chapters - you're really missing some key programming concepts to be jumping right into your own projects.

Comment: Interstellar_Coder's answer below is perfect.

Comment: I´ve checked where´s the sintaxis problem, and the php manual says that arrays cannot be used as keys. That´s why it appears this "Illegal offset type" error. It seems that something could be missing? $month[$user_month]['???'].

Comment: I think you´re right :) Thanks for the help! I´m just reading about all this, but haven´t finished the book yet, and thougth of creating some easy examples to try what I´m learning...

Comment: The $month[$user_month] will only work with radio buttons/single choice - of course your check boxes provide an array, which is what that error is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve used both solutions, but even when the code worked, I couldn´t get all responses to get added to the total sum.

So, After a lot of trying (and due to my lack or information, because I´m still reading W. Jason Gilmore´s manual "Beginning PHP and MySQL Manual"), I got the total sum, and wanted to post it here just in case anyone ever needs something like this:

Instead of:

```
$number = array_sum($selected_months + $selected_days);
print "<br>Your magic Number is... <b>".$number."</b>.<br>"
```

I did:

```
$number1 = array_sum($selected_months);
$number2 = array_sum($selected_days);

$total = $number2 + $number2;
echo $total;
```

There´s a fairly good chance that this is horrible code, and there´s a nicer way to do this, but it works. Thank you guys!!! I couldn´t get this without your help! :)
As I´m a newbie, posting this is the only way that maybe I can contribute here.

Rosamunda